# Passing Stream from ReadAsStreamAsync as API response and avoiding large in memory objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, stream, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working with two API's which are being used to download large documents from an external system.

I call API 1 with some information about a document to be retrieved, API 1 then calls API 2 with that same information acting as a 'middleman'. API 1 gets document binary back which it then passes along to the original caller.

What I'd like to avoid is creating large in memory objects representing these documents and just pass a stream as the response all the way through, is this possible with the described setup ('middleman' API)?

Basic example of what I have (in API 1):

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://example.com/api/getdocs");
request.Content = parameters;

// 'ResponseHeadersRead' - indicate completion on reading of headers and not entire response...
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
     var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

     return this.Ok(stream);
}
else
{
    // Logging/error handling...
}
```

The response from this is being read as a stream by the original caller and then passed to a `FileStreamResult` which downloads the document on the client machine.

My question(s):

- Is the `var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()` line still creating a large in memory object representing the document?
- Does the above stream need to be disposed or will the underlying `HttpContent` take care of cleaning up the stream? If it does need to be disposed, how can I do this whilst still passing a stream response to the caller? (is that even possible?)

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38083206/not-calling-dispose-on-httprequestmessage-and-httpresponsemessage-in-asp-net-cor Basically, as you can see from [the source code](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/System/net/System/Net/Http/HttpRequestMessage.cs#L200), the only thing `HttpRequestMessage.Dispose` does is dispose its `Content` stream, which ASP.Net will do for you if you pass it to `Ok`

Comment: @Charlieface That's brilliant, exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stream` which you are passing to `Ok` should **not** be disposed. `Ok` will wrap the stream and feed it back as a response to the client, so if you dispose it then the response will fail.

Technically speaking, at least according to `IDisposable` mantra, you should dispose `response`. However, doing so will cause it to dispose the stream also, and therefore you should **not** dispose `response` either.

Don't fear that it will cause anything to leak: `HttpResponseMessage` does not dispose anything other than the content stream. See [the below source code](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/System/net/System/Net/Http/HttpRequestMessage.cs#L200):

```cs
     protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
     {
         // The reason for this type to implement IDisposable is that it contains instances of types that implement
         // IDisposable (content). 
         if (disposing && !disposed)
         {
             disposed = true;
             if (content != null)
             {
                 content.Dispose();
             }
         }
     }
```

You **should** however dispose `request` with a `using` block, although that also just disposes the content, in your case `parameters`.

Answer (score 0):

1. `FileStreamResult` reads bytes from an input stream to a buffer (wich is 4kb by default) and writes them to an output stream. So no large in memory object should be created.
2. Input stream read process in `FileStreamResult` is wrapped in `using` statement. It will be disposed correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I know that `FileStreamResult` will dispose of the stream itself internally but my question is specifically about the stream created in the 'middleman' API layer. Does `HttpContent` handle cleaning up of its own resources? If it doesn't, how can I safely dispose of this stream whilst still returning it?